# Unity3D: Adding a Vector3 leads to wrong value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

#### The short version

Im trying to add a Vector3 to another Vector3, which results in wrong values and gets rounded to zero, but works for negative values.
Am i running into some weird overflow and if so, can somebody please explain what is going on there?

#### The long version

I'm gathering the location data from a VR headset (HTC Vive) and calculating the difference to the last frame.
I want to manipulate that value and add it afterwards to a Vector3 for one of the axis.
But for some reason the adding onto another Vector3 fails for positive numbers.

```cs
// Calculating the difference works with float, double or decimal type.
// The difference is a value reaching from ~0.001 to ~0.5.
decimal diff = (decimal)(pos.y - lastPos.y);

// Returns the correct result with both float and decimal.
decimal force = 10;
float manipulatedDiff = (float)(diff * force);

// Add it to another Vector3. Let's say its Vector3.zero for now
Vector3 otherForce = Vector3.zero;
Vector3 difference = otherForce + Vector3.up * manipulatedDiff;

// Suddenly the y-value is 0 (or that small, that i gets rounded to 0)
Debug.Log(difference.y);
```

So let's assume *diff* is **0.1382741**, so *manipulatedDiff* is **1.382741**, but *difference.y* is **0**, instead of **1.382741**.
However, as soon as *diff* becomes negative the value for *difference.y* is correct.

I tried to change up the structure, creating the Vector3-objects in different places, applying them value by value, but it all leads to the same issue.

My best guess would be that i am running into some overflow, because Vector3 works with floats.

Comment: Is the code you've shown here the actual code you're using and finding problems with? I suspect not. This code looks fine to me (except for the odd usage of `decimal` and casting). That *could* be related to the problem as there could be some data loss as a result.

Comment: Also, what if `diff` is *actually* zero because there was no change from `lastPos` to `pos`?

Comment: I simplified the code of course (just forgot to undo the weird typecasting), but in fact, thats the code i'm currently testing with.
I mean, it would be even okayish, if i would lose some preciousness (is that even a word?), but 0.13*10 shouln't be zero

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. As I said I do not see any issue with the code. How are you asserting that the value is zero?

Comment: Just logging to the Unity console. *manipulatedDiff* is the correct value, whereas *difference.y* (not logged as Vector3) is 0 (even checked with ==0f)
Is there any overflow, i could possible run into?

Comment: I tested the code, and it works EXACTLY as you expect it to, and Logs 1.382741. Please review your question, and be sure the code you post replicates your issue. As already noted, I suggest you initialize your variable `decimal force=10.0M;` as casting an int into a decimal might lead to issues.

Comment: Nominating to close this question until there is enough information to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Okay, i finally found the bug. The error was a wrong check in some other condition, i commented back in after posting the question. Thanks everyone.